# Magento Quick Search showing all products, no pagination

Tags: product-list, grid, catalogsearch, search, pagination

Magento Quick Search showing all products with no pagination
Though 9 per page is selected, but still showing all products with that search
[image]

Comment: do you use custom template? do you have the same issue on magneto default template? if you have catalogsearch.xml in your template? can you remove it and test again...

Comment: Do you use any custom extensions related to the search or the catalog? This problem usually happens when you call load on the product collection before the pagination is applied to it.

Comment: As @Marius mentionned, it sounds like a custom code is manipulating the collection before the pagination is applied to it. Check if the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar has been rewritten somewhere and if it has, try disabling the module related to it.